# Microsoft Test Manager "Recommended Test" feature not working with TFS Build 2015 (vnext)

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015, mtm

I'm trying to use the feature "Recommended Test" from Test Manager but the list is always empty.

I did the following:

- I have run the tests on a previous build and testImpact.xml is
  attached for each test
- I have changed the code so that 1 of the 2 must should be recommended.
- I assign the new  build (with the change) and check recommended test against the previous build : the list is empty.

I know that Team Build vNext is missing Features but "Test Impact Analysis is not in the published list :

> With VSO and TFS 2015 we introduced a new version of Team Build that
>   has some great new capabilities, however, we didn’t have time to
>   finish all of the features to bring it to parity with our Xaml build
>   system.  These include, label sources, associate work items and gated
>   builds for Tfvc.  Over the next few months we’ll be delivering these
>   on VSO and then in TFS.
>
> Source: 
>   http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/08/27/ci-experience-futures.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage

Anyone have successfully use Test Impact Analysis with Team Build 2015 (vNext)

Comment: Related, but also unanswered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33478269/tfs2015-determine-impacted-tests-during-vnext-build